# how and where to set css styles for Fontawosomefx icons for mouse hover

Tags: java, javafx, font-awesome, fxml

can some one tell how to set CSS for a button with fontawsome icon on top to change icon fill color when mouse hover in javafx (using fxml) ??

```
tried this css file and attaching to the button ..but no luck..

.icons:hover {
    -fx-fill: white;
    -icons-color: black;
}
```

icons are added like this from fxml

```
 <JFXButton fx:id="viewStaffButton" alignment="CENTER" buttonType="RAISED" graphicTextGap="10.0" onMouseClicked="#onVIewStaffClicked" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="179.0" ripplerFill="WHITE" style="-fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-color: white;" text="View Staff" textFill="WHITE">
                                    <VBox.margin>
                                        <Insets bottom="50.0" />
                                    </VBox.margin>
                                    <graphic>
                                        <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="USERS" size="20" />
                                    </graphic>
                                    <cursor>
                                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                    </cursor>
                                </JFXButton>
```

Comment: I cannot find any `-icons-color` property in the class and `-fx-fill` is missing a `l` in your css.

Comment: @fabian sorry ..mistake noted..but still not working..am i correct with my css tags??

Comment: Having never used FontAwesomeFX before, can you post the minimal amount of code required to create and display an icon? At the very least, what is the qualified name of the class used?

Comment: @Slaw i updated the question with the snippet of my code where i use icons

Answer (score 0):

The CSS class for those icons is `glyph-icon`.

Try replacing `.icons:hover { ... }` with `.glyph-icon:hover { ... }` in css.

Also, you will need to declare  `-icons-color` somewhere above in CSS like root

```
.root{
    -icons-color: red;
}
```

to use it later.